# Secure catalogsearch URL?

Tags: security, https

Whats the rule to makes the search form URL https? I tried:

```
<secure_url>            
    <catalogsearch>/result/</catalogsearch>
</secure_url>
```

But that doesnt do the job. Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Solution:

```
<catalogsearch>/catalogsearch/result/</catalogsearch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
<catalogsearch>/catalogsearch/result/</catalogsearch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<secure_url>            
    <catalogsearch>/catalogsearch/</catalogsearch>
</secure_url>
```

and make sure that this is under the `<frontend>` tag in your `config.xml`

Comment: Thanks, but doesnt work ... its under <frontend> and inside <secure_url>

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, I did, doesnt help. Are you sure its the right way to do it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I assumed it works the same as it does for `customer`.

Comment: How does <catalogsearch_result>/catalogsearch/result/</catalogsearch_result> look to you?

Comment: MAde it work, see my OP

Comment: @user1638055. Post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted